# Interpreting question regarding intervals and inverse

Tags: inverse-function

How would you interpret "for each of the intervals I, give the domain and range of the restriction $f_{I}$ of  $f$  to I and sketch the graph of the inverse of  $f_{I}$ "?

The intervals are (∞,0], [0,2] and [2,∞) and the equation of the function is $f(x)=x^3-3x^2+4$.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have three intervals, and you have to do the same thing for each of the intervals:

1. You have to give the domain of $f_{(-\infty, 0]}$
2. You have to give the range of $f_{(-\infty, 0]}$
3. You have to sketch the graph of the inverse of $f_{(-\infty, 0]}$

Then you have to repeat the three steps two more times. Now, which of the three steps is confusing you?

Comment: How do I go about finding the inverse of the cubic?

Comment: @randb Well the question only says "sketch a graph". So you don't have to probably. Just draw the graph of $f$ and mirror it across the line $y=x$...